# x86 asm strange Array for loop

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly, decompiling

I can't quite makes sense of this code. It seems like a for loop iterating through an array of structs. But it keeps overwriting itself as the index does not jump far enough.

```
                xor     edx, edx
                db      66h, 66h, 66h, 66h
                nop     word ptr cs:[eax+eax+00000000h]
loc_1808450:
                mov     esi, [eax+312]
                mov     esi, [esi+edx*4]
                mov     dword ptr [esi+12], 0
                movsd   xmm0, qword ptr ds:(loc_180815C - 180815Ch)[ecx]
                movsd   qword ptr [esi+4], xmm0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+64], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+82], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+65], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+40], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+44], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+48], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+66], 0FFh
                mov     dword ptr [esi+16], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+71], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+67], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+81], 0
                mov     word ptr [esi+79], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+75], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+87], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+83], 0
                mov     word ptr [esi+95], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+91], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+98], 100
                mov     byte ptr [esi+97], 100
                mov     byte ptr [esi+99], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+100], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+101], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+20], 0FFFFFFFFh
                mov     dword ptr [esi+24], 0FFFFFFFFh
                mov     dword ptr [esi+36], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+28], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+32], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+56], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+52], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+60], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+106], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+102], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+114], 0
                mov     dword ptr [esi+110], 0
                mov     byte ptr [esi+118], 0
                inc     edx
                cmp     edx, 23
                jnz     loc_1808450
```

This is what I understand from the code:

**mov esi, [esi+edx*4]** seems to set the array and
**inc     edx** the update i++

The array is of size 119 and i*4 will never be a big enough memory jump so it ends up overriding the value in
 **movsd   xmm0, qword ptr ds:(loc_180815C - 180815Ch)[ecx]**

Comment: I don’t know how you think the value in EDX, 119 or the movsd relate to each other. EDX is used as an index to get a pointer to memory somewhere. It’s not given how much memory there is, but it might very well have 119 bytes per pointer.

Comment: Sorry I am still new at this. I haven't touched c++ in like 10 years so my pointer assumptions might be very flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code initialize an array of 23 item pointers.

```
mov esi, [eax+312]
```

Here `esi` is start of an array of points and here:

```
mov esi, [esi+edx*4]
```

`esi` is a pointer. You are missing `[]` operator. `esi+edx*4` shows an address of a pointer and value of this pointer goes to `esi`. That `edx*4` is for getting next pointer to object, not object itself. Now this will be initialized. Real code should be something like this (there is no call in your assembly I just wrote like this for simplicity):

```
struct _mystruct *arr[23];

void init_struct(struct _mystruct *item)
{
    ...
}

for (int i=0; i < 23; i++)
    init_struct(arr[i]));
```

Comment: So it is a pointer to an array and not the array itself?
I imagined it was something like this:

`struct _mystruct arr[23];`

Thanks alot

Comment: @SinisterMephisto it is an array of pointers(or better said, pointer to array of pointers if we start looking from `[eax+312]`). In addition, `struct _mystruct *arr[23];` is somehow similar to double pointer access-wise. 1 from array and 1 from type. :)